# How to store and query daily server usage data in mongodb

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I want to store daily cpu and disk stats from our servers in mongodb and query later them for analytics, i want help with how i can store and query the data.

I tried the below structure but i'm unable to query the data for particular date/ date range after storing.

```
    > 
    > db.customer2.find()
    { "_id" : ObjectId("5a677a69b427f6a736044894"), "server" : "s1", "cpuload" : { "2017-11-04T00:00:00Z" : 50,"2017-11-04T00:00:00Z" : 60 }, "disk_usage" : { "2017-11-04T00:00:00Z" : 90, "2017-11-05T00:00:00Z" : 90} }
    { "_id" : ObjectId("5a677a69b427f6a736044894"),  "server" : "s2", "cpuload" : { "2017-11-04T00:00:00Z" : 50,"2017-11-04T00:00:00Z" : 60 }, "disk_usage" : { "2017-11-04T00:00:00Z" : 90, "2017-11-05T00:00:00Z" : 90} }
    > 
    > db.stats2.find({"disk_usage":"2017-11-04T00:00:00Z"})
    >
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your data structure from keyed name value pairs to array of embedded documents.

```
"disk_usage":[
       {"date":ISODate("2017-11-04T00:00:00Z"),"value":60}, 
       {"date":ISODate("2017-11-05T00:00:00Z"),"value":90}
]
```

You can use [`dot notation`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/document/index.html#dot-notation) to apply criteria on date field which will return the document when there is a matched date entry in the "disk_usage" array.

```
db.col.find({"disk_usage.date":ISODate("2017-11-04T00:00:00Z")})
```

You've to use [`$`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/projection/positional/#proj._S_) projection to return the matched date element in "disk_usage".

```
db.col.find({"disk_usage.date":ISODate("2017-11-04T00:00:00Z")}, {"disk_usage.$":1})
```

Comment: Aside from the original question being off topic (really broad and opinion-soliciting), you have suggested a solution with an unbounded array, which will invariably cause issues down the line, both in scale and in document capacity.

Comment: @DavidMakogon Please note this solution is no different from Op's solution in terms of document capacity. This just makes the data queryable and indexable. All the query and update solutions in mongodb are built around array of embedded documents. So this is the most generic way of modelling your data and you plan as your data grows.

Comment: Sorry but that's simply not true. An unbounded array with the potential to exceed the size of a document causes an app failure with no recourse but to introduce an alternative model (or chain documents). Unbounded arrays are the "code smell" of document databases.

Comment: @DavidMakogon Sorry, I respectfully disagree. You can start with array containing all dates and later as data grows you can split the data into different buckets (year/month/day) document and thus keeping the array under document capacity and use aggregation framework to merge the data together to produce the output.